# How to divide two columns element-wise in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, math

I have two columns in my pandas dataframe. I'd like to divide column `A` by column `B`, value by value, and show it as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

csv1 = pd.read_csv('auto$0$0.csv')
csv2 = pd.read_csv('auto$0$8.csv')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(csv1, columns=['Column A', 'Column B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(csv2, columns=['Column A', 'Column B'])

dfnew = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

The columns:

```
Column A  Column B
12        2
14        7
16        8
20        5
```

And the expected result:

```
Result
6
2
2
4
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Just divide the columns:

```
In [158]:
df['Result'] = df['Column A']/df['Column B']
df

Out[158]:
   Column A  Column B  Result
0        12         2     6.0
1        14         7     2.0
2        16         8     2.0
3        20         5     4.0
```

Answer (score 6):

### [`Series.div()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html)

> Equivalent to the `/` operator but with support to substitute a `fill_value` for missing data in either one of the inputs.

So normally `div()` is the same as `/`:

```
df['C'] = df.A.div(df.B)
#         df.A / df.B
```

But `div()`'s `fill_value` is more concise than 2x `fillna()`:

```
df['C'] = df.A.div(df.B, fill_value=-1)
#         df.A.fillna(-1) / df.B.fillna(-1)
```

And `div()`'s method chaining is more idiomatic:

```
df['C'] = df.A.div(df.B).cumsum().add(1).gt(10)
#         ((df.A / df.B).cumsum() + 1) > 10
```

---

Note that when dividing a *DataFrame* with another DataFrame or Series, [`DataFrame.div()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) also supports broadcasting across an `axis` or MultiIndex `level`.

Answer (score 3):

`div` or `/` doesn't work if the indices don't match. It's common when the columns come from different dataframes or if some rows are divided by some other rows in the same dataframe. In that case, convert the divisor column into numpy array.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': range(10,15)}, index=range(10,15))

df1['C'] = df1['A'] / df2['B']             # <---- Bunch of NaNs
df1['C'] = df1['A'] / df2['B'].values      # <---- OK
df1['C'] = df1['A'].div(df2['B'].values)   # <---- OK
```