# How to do columnwise operations in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like:

```
 sample parameter1 parameter2 parameter3
 A      9           6         3        
 B      4           5         7
 C      1           5         8
```

and I want to do an operation that does something like:

```
for sample in dataframe:
    df['new parameter'] = df[sample, parameter1]/df[sample, parameter2]
```

so far I have tried:

```
df2.loc['ratio'] = df2.loc['reads mapped']/df2.loc['raw total sequences']
```

but I get the error:

```
KeyError: 'the label [reads mapped] is not in the [index]'
```

when I know well that it is in the index, so I figure I am missing some concept somewhere. Any help is much appreciated!

I should add that the parameter values are floats, just in case that is a problem as well!

Comment: I think you just want `df.parameter1.div(df.parameter2)`

Comment: Have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619631/how-to-divide-two-column-in-a-dataframe

Comment: I have seen this and tried it. It throws me lots of errors, mostly that my index doesn't exist in the indices. I have verified that it does exist in the indices, and I think that is happening because "parameter1" isn't a string value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `.loc` first expects row indices, then column indices, so the following should work, since you wanted to do column-wise operations:

```
 df2['ratio'] = df2.loc[:, 'reads mapped'] / df2.loc[:, 'raw total sequences']
```

You can find more info in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for! Any idea why I'm getting this error? : A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: This is a `SettingWithCopyWarning` and it means df2 is just a slice of some other DataFrame. You can get around this by adding `.copy()` to whatever place in the code where you first make df2 from another DataFrame.

Comment: see also the following link: 
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Comment: @GAD Did that help you?

Comment: Yes! adding .copy() allows me to do operations the way you would expect. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad it helped!