# How to perform element wise operation on two sets of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, operation

I have the dataframe:

```
 c1 | c2 | c3 | c4
 5  |  4 | 9  | 3
```

How could I perform element wise division (or some other operation) between c1/c2 and c3/c4

So that the outcome is:

```
.5555 | 1.33333
```

I've tried:

```
df[['c1', 'c2']].div(df[['c3', 'c4']], axis='index'))
```

But that just resulted in NaNs.

Comment: Yes, a dataframe with 2 columns, one for the outcome of c1/c3 and the other for the outcome of c2/c4. Sorry I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty straightforward, just divide by the values

```
df[['c1', 'c2']]/df[['c3','c4']].values
```

Orders matter, so make sure to use correct ordering in the denominator. No need to recreate the DataFrame

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to drop down to NumPy and create a new dataframe:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(df[['c1', 'c2']].values / df[['c3', 'c4']].values)

print(res)

          0         1
0  0.555556  1.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive I'm understanding your question correctly , but you can literally just divide the series.

```
df['c1/c2'] = df['c1'] / df['c2']
```

See this answer: [How to divide two column in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619631/how-to-divide-two-column-in-a-dataframe)

EDIT: Okay, I understand what OPs asking now.. Please see other answer.

Comment: Yes but I want to vectorize the entire operation, so that I don't have to for-loop through the pairs of columns

Comment: This doesn't match OP's desired output.