# Add a column in a dataframe resulting from an operation between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
      rate      amount            datetime
0      935  255.058618 2020-07-07 01:10:00
1      942  234.305349 2020-07-07 01:10:00
2      943  218.942727 2020-07-07 01:10:00
3      946  202.203811 2020-07-07 01:10:00
4      950  297.575301 2020-07-07 01:10:00
5      951  302.152497 2020-07-07 01:10:00
```

How can I add, for each row, a column called `fraction` whose value is `amount/rate`? The output should be something like this:

```
      rate      amount            datetime fraction
0      935  255.058618 2020-07-07 01:10:00 0.27
...
```

I tried the following, but of course it didn't work:

```
for x in MyData:
    x['fraction'] = x['amount']/x['rate']
```

Is there any way to do this, maybe with list comprehension?

Comment: `df['fraction'] = df['amount']/df['rate']`

Comment: @pythonic833 you can also explain why this work properly.

Comment: That is just an element by element division as with `numpy` arrays

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to divide two column in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619631/how-to-divide-two-column-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

`MyData['fraction'] = MyData['amount']/MyData['rate']`

Long:
In Pandas most operation should be done on whole dataset, not row-by-row, but at-all. You should definitely avoid iterating over rows.