# Iterate through the column in padas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

I have a CSV file and I am trying to calculate the value by multiplying each value of column "a" with every value of column "b". I have written down a code but right now it only multiplies one specific value at a time. For example, currently, my code prints the multiplication of the 1st value of column "a" by iterating the values of the column "a" in the numerator and then dividing it with the multiplication of the first value of column "b" with all the values of column "b" and I have to repeat the process again for other values of the column "a". I am a newbie in python, can anyone suggest to me how to implement my codes in the right way to iterate them in one run? That is first it takes the first value of column "a" and then calculate the solution with all the values of column "b" and then take the second value of column "a" and then repeat the process till it reaches the last value of column "a". The data looks like this:

[image]

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("/home/Documents/test.csv")

for num in data.columns[0]:
    for den in data.columns[1]:
        x = (((data.at[0,'a'])*data[num]))/((data.at[0,'b'])*data[den])
print(x)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: no need to loop, just do `df['a']/df['b']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to divide two columns element-wise in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619631/how-to-divide-two-columns-element-wise-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try column indexing.
Here is the solution.

```
result = df['a']/df['b']
```

This will do operation for all the column values.

Then you can print the result

```
print(result)
```

Output:

[image]